# In Eclipse, how to export a project to ZIP including referenced libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, zip

My lecturer required a ZIP file containing my project, which he will import into Eclipse on his machine. I cannot guarantee he has jUnit on his machine, but I used jUnit in my project.

If I simply export the project to a ZIP (File > Export > Archive File ...) **will the ZIP include (my version of) jUnit**? And if not, how can I include jUnit in the ZIP?

**Edit**: Tested the import of a ZIP file, generated as above, on a fresh installation of Eclipse, on a virtual machine, and jUnit was there. When inspecting the .class file of the project I saw that it provides a URL to jUnit. So I guess my question has become: **Where does Eclipse import jUnit from? And will this work in any setup of Eclipse (i.e. OS, version of Eclipse)?**

Comment: is it a maven project ?

Comment: Nope, just a regular Java project  (File > New > Java Project).

Comment: The URL to junit in your .classPath must be the path of the jar file in your machine. This will be added when you import/add the junit archives to your project. I don't think eclipse is doing this import automatically. It is just referring from the path that you have given. Hence it won't work in your lecturer machine if you share only the project. You need to separately share the junit jar file as well

Comment: Thanks but I don't have a jUnit JAR on my machine. This is the URL in the .classpath file: org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4 .

Comment: Basically in the class path entry, what i referred was when the kind is lib. In your case, the entry kind may be con. In that case the library files are available with eclipse itself. Please go through the below link. It might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960054/whats-the-use-of-the-configuration-in-classpath-for-eclipse-project-org-eclip

Comment: Ok. So, as @Christian said below, JUnit comes with Eclipse. Which also means that if this ZIP is imported into an Eclipse that doesn't have the version of JUnit I am using (4), the tests won't run. If you wish to summarize this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit comes with eclipse itself. It is usually the latest version. If you want to use any other version of Junit then you have to manually import the libraries to your project.

Now coming to your question that if you archive the project and share it with your lecturer then the zip file will not have the Junit library but it gets imported from eclipse libraries when the project is built. Again it is a specific version of JUnit depending on which eclipse version you are using. Few more details are mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960054/whats-the-use-of-the-configuration-in-classpath-for-eclipse-project-org-eclip)

You can check the version of Junit that eclipse provides as mentioned 
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729403/how-to-know-the-version-of-junit-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

`JUnit` comes standard with the download of any version of Eclipse. To use it, a new `.java` file needs to be created (`File > New > JUnit Test Case`). Find your program package and then name your `.java` file (usually something similar to the class which is being tested)

**Example:**
Name: HelloWorldTest
Class under test: HelloWorld

If you ever find the `JUnit` library is corrupt or isn't working again, you can download the current version straight from the [web site](http://junit.org)

Comment: Thank you Christian. Your answer helped me realise that Eclipse already has JUnit, but @Sravya's answer gives more details.